# In Apache Karaf, how can a KAR file instruct Karaf to install features?

Tags: osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle, karaf

I have a KAR file which I produced for Apache Karaf.

Now to get my KAR to run in Karaf 2.4.1 I must manually type into Karaf console the following to allow declarative services to work.

```
features:install scr
```

Is there a way for my KAR file to instruct Karaf to install this **scr** automatically?

The point is that I would like to be able to deploy a KAR by just dropping it into Karaf deploy folder without having to do any manual command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A KAR contains a features XML file, correct? Add the scr feature into your features XML file as a dependent feature. See the section on **Dependent Features** in [Karaf Provisioning](https://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest-2.3.x/users-guide/provisioning.html).